# rewriting definition of `not` in Ruby's Object

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

really confused about what this RubyMonk examples does. `class Not` is supposed to return an object capable of inverting calls to `Object#not`.

```
class Object
  def not
    Not.new(self)
  end

  class Not
    def initialize(original)
      @original = original
    end

    def method_missing(sym, *args, &blk)
      !@original.send(sym, *args, &blk)
    end
  end
end

class Person
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def smith?
    @name == "Smith"
  end
end
```

and this is how the test goes

```
puts Person.new("Smith").not.smith?
puts Person.new("Ziggy").not.smith?
```

what I don't understand is

1. in what ways does this change the built-in definition of method `not`?
2. when passing arguments to `not`, how does it "travel"? it goes to `not` method, after which a new instance of `class Not` is created and it gets passed to that instance?
3. what is need for the `method_missing`? what method could there possibly be missing in this scenario? and what does it do when there is a method missing? it's just being told to not send the arguments to `@original` and that's it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`method_missing` in `Not` class is the real magic. These is the scenario:

```
Person.new("Smith")   # you create new person
Person.new("Smith").not # calls method #not on the person object instance
# the method #not will create new instance of the class Not and passing self as argument
# passing the person on which you have called the method 
# then the initialize method of the Not class gets called
# because you want to create new object of the Not class and 
# @original is the person on which you have called the method #not
Person.new("Smith").not.smith?  # will call method #smith? on the Not object instance
```

what happened till now

```
person = Person.new("Smith")
not_class_object = person.not
not_class_object.smith? # there is no method named #smith? in the Not class
```

If no method exists it check all hierarchy and see if anything in the inheritance chain has implemented the `smith?` method. If none has implemented the `smith?` method then Ruby will call `method_missing` the same way, and you have changed the behavior of the `method_missing` for the `Not` class.

Now it will get the `@original` which is the `person` object and call the method on the person object, this Person instance object has implemented the method, and when the result comes we will just negate the outcome. So if the `smith?` method returns true for the person calling `not.smith?` will return false, because `smith?` method returns true we negate the value and get false, and if it returns false, when we negate you get true.

Edit:

`Person` is extension of `Object`, but there is no connection between `Not` and `Person`, `Person` is not extending `Not` and `Not` is not extending `Person`.

`Not` is class inside `Object` and it has no method named `smith?`, instance object of `Person` got `smith?` method. That is why it does not find `smith?` method on the `Not` instance object, and then it calls `method_missing` from the inheritance chain, and you have implemented `method_missing` for the `Not` class that it takes the object on which you have called `not` method of `Object` class and created instance object from `Not` class with parameter as `Person` instance object.

Edit2:

```
class NotPerson
   ...
   # some code
   ...
end

p1 = Person.new("Smith")
p2 = Person.new("Ziggy")
p3 = NotPerson.new("something")
p1.smith?  # -> true
p2.smith?  # -> false
p3.smith?  #  Error there is no method named #smith? in NotPerson class

not_p1 = p1.not
not_p2 = p2.not
not_p3 = p3.not
not_p1.smith? # -> false
# Because there is no method #smith? on #not class, and #method_missing is called
not_p1.smith? # is eqivavlent to
!(p1.smith?)

not_p2.smith? # -> true
not_p3.smith? # Error there is no method #smith? definedin NotPerson class
```

Edit3:

check also some references how `method_missing` is working

[method_missing](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing)

[second_example](http://technicalpickles.com/posts/using-method_missing-and-respond_to-to-create-dynamic-methods/)

Comment: so, Ruby does find `smith?` method in the inheritance chain and in this case `method_missing` does not get called?

Comment: Ruby does not find `smith?` method in inheritance chain, because there is no `smith?` method on object of `Not` class, and `method_missing` is called.

Comment: oh ok, I was thinking that it would find `smith?` because `Person` is an extension of `Object`, but I doesn't work like that?

Comment: I keep coming back to this and still can't wrap my head around it. if ruby is not finding `smith?` method, then why does `Person.new("Smith").not.smith?` and `Person.new("Ziggy").not.smith?` yield `false` and `true` respectively?

Comment: wouldn't `not_p1.smith?` and `not_p2.smith?` both produce the same result? I

Answer (score 3):

Answering your question #1:

> in what ways does this change the built-in definition of method `not`?

a) It doesn't, because b) `not` isn't a method, it's a keyword, and as such its definition is baked into the language specification.

More precisely: the `not` keyword is translated to a call to the method `!`, just like the `!` operator, so all three of the following are equivalent:

```
not foo
!foo
foo.!
```

Comment: `not` and `!` differ in precedence, however: `! false && false #=> false; not false && false #=> true `.